# Is there a @NonNullByDefault annotation in IDEA?

Tags: java, null, intellij-idea, static-analysis

Eclipse has the `@NonNullByDefault` annotation, which treats all values as `@NonNull` unless you explicitly annotate them as `@Nullable`.

Is there an equivalent option in IntelliJ IDEA, or do you have to always use `@Nonnull`?

Comment: Isn't that `@Nonnull` instead (JSR 305)? IDEA can use `@NotNull`, but this is a different annotation.

Comment: By the way, what use would you make of that annotation? Is that for static source code analysis? IDEA can use FindBugs, it has a plugin for that. As to using these annotations, I follow Guice's advice: method parameters cannot be null unless annotated with `@Nullable`. But that is a question of policy...

Comment: @fge Our coding policy is to use the Eclipse annotations including `@NonNullByDefault`. So, my question is whether IDEA be configured to emulate Eclipse' null analysis. `@NonNullByDefault` seems to be the tricky part.

Comment: please, vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65566

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is currently not supported by IDEA.

As a proof, see lena's link about the open feature request to [allow 'NotNull' as the default element behavior for a given class or package](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65566).

Maybe a similar feature will be become standard with [JSR-305](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/), which may include the [`@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.java) annotation and also the opposite annotation [`@ParametersAreNullableByDefault`](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.java). Note that in contrast to `@NonNullByDefault`, return values are not covered by those two annotations. So, you still had to annotate the return value explicitely.

All that doesn't change the current state, though. Neither has JSR-305 become a standard, nor does IDEA implement it.

Comment: IDEA now support @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/@parametersarenonnullbydefault-annotation.html

Comment: ^ link in comment is broken... this one works (for now...): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/parametersarenonnullbydefault-annotation.html

Answer (score 11):

Idea version 14 will include support for the JSR 305 "@TypeQualifierDefault" annotation, which allows the user to create a custom annotation, to be used on a package declaration in a package-info.java file, that specifies that everything in that package (not just parameters, but method return values, local variables, etc.) will be implicitly annotated as not allowing null values.

Unfortunately, this doesn't (currently) recursively affect subpackages, so each subpackage has to have a package-info.java file too, declaring that subpackage to use the annotation.

See here for details and an example of use:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125281

Note that this is already implemented in Early Access Program (EAP) builds.

Comment: I can verify that this approach works with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Community Edition).